# Angular 6 Lazy Loaded Components Not Rendering

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am having an issue implementing lazy loading that is causing me a ton of frustration. I am lazy loading two modules currently as shown below in my app-routing.module.ts:

```
{
  path: 'home',
  loadChildren: './general/general.module#GeneralModule'
},
{
  path: 'admin',
  canLoad: [AdminGuard],
  loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
},
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/home',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
  path: '**',
  component: PageNotFoundComponent
}
```

the general module loads fine and I can navigate to all components in that module. here is this routing setup:

```
{
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent,
  canActivate: [CanActivateLogin]
},
{
  path: 'manage-account',
  component: ManageAccountComponent,
  canActivate: [CanActivateLogin]
},
{
  path: 'register',
  component: RegisterComponent,
  canActivate: [CanActivateLogin]
},
{
  path: '',
  component: HomepageComponent
}
```

when trying to access the admin module, I am correctly hitting my CanLoad guard and it returns a truthy value:

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanLoad {
constructor(
  private store: Store<AppState>
) { }

canLoad(route: Route): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
return this.store.select(userSelectors.getUserAccessLevel).pipe(
  map(access => access === ROLE_SYSTEM_ADMIN)
  );
}
}
```

I would assume it has something to do with my admin router setup, but as of right now it is incredibly simple and still not working:

```
{
  path: 'manage-users',
  component: ManageUsersComponent
},
{
  path: '',
  component: LandingPageComponent
}
```

any help would be tremendously appreciated

Comment: have you tried without can load ?

Comment: I did try that thinking maybe the guard wasn't resolving correctly and it still didn't work. Do you think it could have anything to do with running via ng serve?

Comment: apparently canLoad is different than canActivate: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18991

I must have had a bad build when I checked without canLoad earlier because I got it working based on this thread.